# grep strings between "{{_(" and ")}}"

Tags: regex, grep

I want to parse html files to extract strings between "{{_(" and ")}}" using GREP. I tried something like this:

```
grep '"[^{{_(|)}}$]"' *.html
```

but it didn't work.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `grep -oP '(?<={{_\().+?(?=\)}})' file`

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: {{_("SOME TEXT_HERE")}} -> grep -> "SOME_TEXT_HERE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
grep -oP '(?<={{_\().+?(?=\)}})' file
```

**Details**

- `-o` - output only matched substrings
- `-P` - enable the PCRE regex engine
- `(?<={{_\().+?(?=\)}})` match:

  - `(?<={{_\()` - a location that is immediately preceded with `{{+(`
  - `.+?` - any 1 or more more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `(?=\)}})` - a location that is immediately followed with `)}}` .

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SLBTPt/1).

Answer (score 1):

@Wiktor Stribiżew's answer works really good. However, if you have multiple files, you would get an output like this, where the respective file name per each match is also displayed:

```
foo.html: content abc
foo.html: test 123
bar.html: first match
bar.html: second match
```

So, if you are only interested in the matching string as output, you can try `sed` instead

```
sed -n 's/.*{{_(\(.*\))}}.*/\1/p' *.html
```

You can also count the unique occurrence of matches and things like that...

Update:

Or just use the `-h | --no-filename` with the grep that @Wiktor Stribiżew has provided.

```
grep -h -oP '(?<={{_\().+?(?=\)}})' *.html
```

Or the `-c` flag in order to display the count of matches per each file:

```
grep -c -oP '(?<={{_\().+?(?=\)}})' *.html
```

Comment: Thank you Kenan!!

Answer (score -1):

As in the posts before with it is possible to grep the value of an HTML property.

placeholder="SOME TEXT_HERE" -> grep -> "SOME TEXT_HERE"

grep -oP '(?<=placeholder=").+?(?=")' *html